# How to use python 2 for a specific project?

Tags: python, emacs, elpy

My global elpy settings are the following

```
RPC Python........: 3.5.3 (/usr/bin/python3)
Interactive Python: ipython3 (/usr/bin/ipython3)
```

I need to work on a project that uses python 2. How do I do that without changing global settings?

Comment: I removed these global settings, created a python 2 virtualenv for the project, did `M-x pyvenv-workon` for that virtualenv and installed all required python modules like jedi and flake8 in it. Everything seems to work now, but my global elpy python is now python2 :(

Comment: using buffer local variables should handle this gracefully.